# using ...spread, but redux still throws warning about state mutation

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

Redux throws Warning on dispatch:

```
Error: A state mutation was detected inside a dispatch, in the path: 
roundHistory.2.tickets. Take a look at the reducer(s) handling the action {"type":"ARCHIVE_TICKETS","roundId":"575acd8373e574282ef18717","data":[{"_id":"575acd9573e574282ef18718","value":7,"user_id":"574c72156f355fc723ecdbbf","round_id":"575acd8373e574282ef18717","__v":0},{"_id":"575acd9573e574282ef18719","value":9,"user_id":"574c72156f355fc723ecdbbf","round_id":"575acd8373e574282ef18717","__v":0},{"_id":"575acd9573e574282ef1871a","value":8,"user_id":"574c72156f355fc723ecdbbf","round_id":"575acd8373e574282ef18717","__v":0},{"_id":"575acdac73e574282ef1871b","value":19,"user_id":"574c72156f355fc723ecdbbf","round_id":"575acd8373e574282ef18717","__v":0},{"_id":"575ad50c4c17851c12a3ec23","value":29,"user_id":"57522f0b1f08fc4257b9cbc6","round_id":"575acd8373e574282ef18717","__v":0},{"_id":"575ad50c4c17851c12a3ec24","value":28,"user_id":"57522f0b1f08fc4257b9cbc6","round_id":"575acd8373e574282ef18717","__v":0},{"_id":"575ad
```

The only reducer handling `ARCHIVE_TICKETS` action is this one:

```
case 'ARCHIVE_TICKETS' :
  var archive = [...state.roundHistory];
  for (var i in archive) {
    if (archive[i]._id === action.roundId) {
      archive[i].tickets = action.data;
    }
  }
  return Object.assign({}, state, {
    roundHistory: archive
  });
```

How can it mutate the state if i use [...spread]?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The `[...state.roundHistory]` here is similar to `[].concat(state.roundHistory)`.  It's creating a new array, but the objects *in* the array are shared with `state.roundHistory`.  If you want to mutate them you'll need to make copies of each item.

You can do this using `Object.assign`, similar to how what you did for your return value:

```
var archive = state.roundHistory.map(value => Object.assign({}, value));
```

Or (as you suggested in your own answer), you can use object-spread notation to return an array with same object values:

```
var archive = state.roundHistory.map(value => ({...value}));
```

Comment: Excellent! Exactly what i realised few minutes ago but in even more elegant way.

Comment: Hi, I tried this  export default (state, action) => {
  return Object.assign({}, {
   ...state,
   messages: state.messages.map(value => Object.assign({}, value)).concat(action.payload)
  })
 } still have the error please view https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58120646/a-state-mutation-was-detected-inside-a-dispatch-not-in-between-dispatch

Answer (score 1):

Okay i got it. Spreading an array of objects gives a new array but with links to same objects. To avoid the mutation, i added this line:
         **`archive[i] = {...state.roundHistory[i]};`**

```
case 'ARCHIVE_TICKETS' :
  var archive = [...state.roundHistory];
  for (var i in archive) {
    archive[i] = {...state.roundHistory[i]};
    if (archive[i]._id === action.roundId) {
      archive[i].tickets = action.data;
    }
  }
  return Object.assign({}, state, {
    roundHistory: archive
  });
```