# Changing state object on reducer

Tags: reactjs, reduce

I am trying to change an object on my reducer in react, as I have read elsewhere, Object.assign creates a new copy on the object but the elements are the same (https://stackoverflow.com/a/37819614/3808307), so I keep getting

> Invariant violation, state mutation was detected inside dispatch

when trying

```
let newTravelersObject = Object.assign({}, state.travelers);
```

I suppose if I had an array instead, I could use map, I have tried also using loadhash _.mapValues but get the same error.

The other solution would be to restructure my code to have an array instead of an object, but I don't think I should be doing that, I refuse to belive it can't be done

state.travelers object

```
{
  "results": [
    {"id" : 34,
      "name": "",
      "enemies" : [
        {"profession": "Dentist", "id": 54},
        {"profession": "Police officer", "id": 471}
    },  
    {"id" : 52,
      "name": "Alicia",
      "enemies" : [
        {"profession": "Architect", "id": 61}
    },
    ...
  ],
  "count": 7
}



case types.ADD_ENEMY_SUCCESS:

  let newTraverlersObject = Object.assign({}, state.travelers);     

  let id = _.findIndex(newTraverlersObject.results, ["id", action.enemy.traveler_id]);
  newTraverlersObject.results[id].enemies.push({"id": action.enemy.id, "profession": action.enemy.profession});


  return Object.assign({}, state, {
    travelers: newTravelersObject
  });
```

Constructor of the class where state is

```
class TravelersPage extends React.Component {
  constructor(props, context){
    super(props, context);
    this.state = {
      travelers: Object.assign({}, props.travelers),
      currentTravelerId: null,
      loading: true,
      ...
    };
```

Comment: what is the shape of your object?

Comment: post the rest the code in your dispatch call

Comment: show `consrtuctor` where `state` is , preferably entire component

Comment: are you returning newTravelersObject from the switch statement?

Comment: @Sag1v Hi, I added it

Comment: @BravoZulu I added it, thank you

Comment: @Jay yes, it is inside the switch statement

Comment: Hi @Aaqib, I added it, let me know if you need anything else, thanks to all

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are mutating the nested objects, for example `results[id].enemies.push`.
Note that `.findIndex` will return a shallow copy and not a deep copy.

I would suggests to rethink the pattern here and consider a more concise and readable flow.

Just return a new object but map over the results array and return the travelers that are not with the same `traveler_id` as is, when you do find the relevant `traveler` return a new object and override the `enemies` array of it, return a new array with the ES2015 spread feature and add the new enemy object in the end.

Here is a running example:

```js
const newItems = {
  "results": [{
    "id": 34,
    "name": "",
    "enemies": [{
      "profession": "Dentist",
      "id": 54
    }, {
      "profession": "Police officer",
      "id": 471
    }]
  }, {
    "id": 52,
    "name": "Alicia",
    "enemies": [{
      "profession": "Architect",
      "id": 61
    }],
  }]
};
const action = {
  type: 'ADD_ENEMY_SUCCESS',
  enemy: {
    id: 999,
    traveler_id: 34,
    profession: 'my new proffesion!!!'
  }
};
const travelersReducer = (state = {}, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'ADD_ENEMY_SUCCESS':
      {
        const {
          enemy: {
            id,
            traveler_id,
            profession
          }
        } = action;
        const nextState = {
          ...state,
          results: state.results.map(traveler => {
            if (traveler.id !== traveler_id) return traveler; // this is not out target, return the object as is
            return { // return a new object
              ...traveler,
              enemies: [
                ...traveler.enemies, { // new enemy
                  id,
                  profession,
                }
              ]
            }
          })
        };
        return nextState;
      }
      defualt: return state;
  }
}

console.log(travelersReducer(newItems, action));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
```

I think you should add more reducers, my rule of thumb is to create a reducer per entity (travelersReducer, travelerReducer, enemiesReducer, enemyReducer...).

I've actually [answered a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47611726/3148807) not a while ago and included an example with creating more reducers.

Note that instead of using `Object.assign` i have used the [object spread feature](https://redux.js.org/docs/recipes/UsingObjectSpreadOperator.html#using-object-spread-operator) which is a proposal [but in stage 3](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-object-rest-spread).

Comment: Thank you, you have been very helpful. I will have to look into it in detail to understand it better